# Remove empty lines from Xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a very long Xcode project it has many empty lines which make vey difficult for me to navigate through the project.Is there any short key to remove empty lines from selected code?

```
 [inboxmessagesarray removeAllObjects];
    [checkimageArray removeAllObjects];


    NSMutableDictionary *callDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    [callDict setObject:@"messages-getModuleMessages" forKey:@"call"];
    [callDict setObject:FB_API_KEY forKey:@"accessSecret"];
    NSString *x=[FBUserManager sharedUserManager].authToken;
    [callDict setObject:x forKey:@"authToken"];
    [callDict setObject:@"json" forKey:@"format"];

    [callDict setObject:@"archived" forKey:@"callType"];


    FBGenericWebHandler *handler = [[FBGenericWebHandler alloc] init];
    handler.delegate = self;
    [handler ArchivesMessages:callDict];
    handler = nil;
   [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
```

Comment: You can just do a global search and replace throughout the project, e.g. change two or more empty lines (or rather lines containing only white space) to one empty line.

Comment: Add to plugin in your Xcode to remove space line to Your code. See my answwer.

Comment: @PaulR please explain your suggestions with more details... looks like way better, but i need more details please. Step by step.

Comment: @IanMashed: Shift-Command-F for global search and replace, then change all occurrences of 2 blank lines to 1 blank line (or whatever else you need). Use a regex if you have blank lines containing tabs/spaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You installed ClangFormat-Xcode plugin in your Xcode. remove Unnecessary space from code in your project.

Download : [ClangFormat-Xcode](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode)

See Below :

[image]

Comment: is there anything simpler ? this solutions looks too complicated

Comment: This plugin no longer supported. For **Xcode 8+** you could use similar tool [XcodeClangFormat](https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat)

Comment: Oky. I will upadte have more way.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions

Replace: ^\s*$
With:       (leave blank/nil)

And the current file will have all blank lines removed.

Comment: This was super helpful to select the blank lines, and I wasn't able to replace the blank line when I left the "with" field blank